# Avoid mix of arithmetic precision in expressions - for constant numbers

Tags: c++, types, precision

My static analysis tool has a rule to not mix arithmetic precision in expressions. Taking the code below:

```
unsigned short minutes = 0;
unsigned short minutesTens = 3;
unsigned short minutesUnits = 52;

minutes = (minutesTens * 10) + usMinutesUnits; // <---- rule violation here
```

So all variables are `"unsigned short";` `"minutesTens * 10"` must not be an unsigned short. I assume that "10" is an "integer", so does this mean that I must do:

```
minutes = (minutesTens * 10U) + usMinutesUnits;
```

And if so, is this really necessary? or is the rule overly strict?

Comment: It would be for readability otherwise to the reviewer it just seems like a magic number of an unknown type participating in an expression. I know lint picks this up as an implicit arithmetic conversion.

Comment: Does you analyzer complain about `minutes = (minutesTens * 10U) + usMinutesUnits;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am presuming so for the moment, its a large build and a takes even longer to run the analysis. But the question really is just that last part - "is that really necessary? or is the rule over strict?"

Comment: Well the problem is once you go to a larger type you may overflow the smaller type giving you an incorrect result.  If I were you I would use `int` and not worry about.  There is a very big debate on the subject but I am in the camp that says: use `int` until you need something bigger and if you do then use `long long`.  `unsigned` types should be reserved for when you need to do bit manipulations.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I agree (like your idea +1) - I mean obviously a larger type can overflow smaller types - but here it is a small constant number... not a variable who's value could be too large... so still not really sure about that.

Comment: Note that operands of type `unsigned short` in arithmetic expressions are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` (depending on the relative sizes of `int` and `short`), so the issue of "going to a larger type" is present regardless of whether that constant is an `unsigned short` or an `unsigned int`. As @NathanOliver implies, this is premature optimization. Just use `int` unless there's a compelling reason to use something else.

Comment: @Pete Becker not to mention that `int` is likely to be the "natural" size for the target machine to work with, so it may actually be faster than the smaller type as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm in the fixed-width-type camp for sure.... except for deliberately abstracted environment-defined quantities such as the range of array dimensions, for which we shall of course use `size_t`. :) `ssize_t` for the result of POSIX socket functions, etc.. In fact, as I use `size_t` for loop counters and fixed-width types for application-domain stuff, I don't think I've written `int` in months. Well, until now ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit (and others) This is just a snippet - I would def change the types all over, but its not practical for this code-base :( But question for `size_t`. Lets say I want to use this everywhere - this is an unsigned value of some sort (depending on platform I guess), so would you not still have to "cast" the constant number to unsigned (e.g. `10U` instead of `10`) to satisfy the static-analysis rule?

Comment: @code_fodder: Yes. Worse (depending on how picky this tool is), `10U` may be `unsigned int` not `size_t`, and `unsigned int` may not be `size_t`.